# Bash line wrapping doesn't work on serial terminal like Minicom

Tags: linux, bash, embedded-linux, gnu

I have an embedded Linux system with BusyBox on it. BusyBox comes with ash as its default shell, but I need additional features so I want to install bash.

I have installed bash, and ran it on the system, but my problem is that whenever I write a long command and the shell needs to go down a line, instead it comes back to the start of the current line and runs over the beginning of the command.

for example:
I write:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

I get:

```
bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Instead of:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
```

I will note that the command does still work. Which means that only the display is ruined. The default shell (ash) does know how to handle this situation.

I looked in to the problem and examined the binary that the shell produces in the serial port when it gets to the end of the line and it does only send \r and no \n (ash sends \r\r\n and that is why it works well).

If I connect to the device from my Ubuntu via ssh and use the bash shell it works well. I assume that is because the Ubuntu terminal takes care of the line ordering.

Additional things I have tested:

- I have seen a lot of posts that say that similar things could happen because of my PS1 variable. I have tried to change it and even just put one character ($) in it with no special or unprintable characters and the problem persists.
- I have tried to configure the system variable $TERM that is used by bash (the default is vt102 and I changed it to xterm), this didn't make any difference.
- I have tried to mess around with the $COLUMNS system variable and change its value and the bash does respond to the change. The only problem is that when it recognizes it needs to move to the next line it produces \r instead of \n.

Is there any way of solving this? Maybe some system variable that tells the bash which string to write when moving to the next line? 
Or maybe a flag that I can change when I compile bash?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `TERM=dumb`?

Comment: I have tried, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Easy workaround for this is - use terminal that is exactly 80 characters wide.

Also 'resize' command (that typically comes with 'xterm' package) can help here - after it is executed inside session, newline-related behavior of command line should become better.

Comment: This is not really good for me, because I want to communicate with the system from different computers with different terminals and I don't want to configure the terminals every time I'm communicating with it.